# Html5 Canvas and base64 image

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have a base64 image which looks like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAADwCA......
```

is there a way i can draw this on a canvas using the above encoded image? Does anyone have an example of this.

**Edited:**

This is working for me and its drawing the image only when its an image and not **base64**

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var pos = 0, ctx = null, ctx2 = null,saveCB, image = [], image2 = new Image();

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');


        var image2 = new Image();

        canvas.setAttribute('width', 320);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', 240);
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);

        var saveCB = function (data) {
            var col = data.split(';');
            var img = image;
            for (var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
                var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
                img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
                pos += 4;
            }

            if (pos >= 4 * 320 * 240) {
                ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
                foto = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $("#photo").val(foto);
                alert($("#photo").val()); 


                ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
                ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
                image2.src = 'http://blackberry12.com/uploads/allimg/110311/2-110311153Z90-L.jpg';
                ctx2.drawImage(image2,0,0);           

                pos = 0;
            }
        };
</script>
```

if i change image2.src to foto or $("#photo").val() i am not getting anything just a white canvas.

**Edited**
From my investigation i am getting the same base64 code every time i take a pic and encode. It seems like the base64 code is really a white screen. Can anyone help here, cant see where i made the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,.............";
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

The image is immediately available for drawing.

Comment: Example of it working, if you'll excuse the shameless self-promotion, go to http://pokefarm.org/ and type the Konami code (`↑↑↓↓←→←→BA<space>` - don't press Shift) you'll get a minigame I made that uses this exact technique to load its images.

Comment: ok great thanks i am going to try this out will let you know how it goes

Comment: the input field that is receiving the value is being populated by jquery how can i listen for changes to that field? The change, live events are not working without user interaction

Comment: Hmm... Is there any way you can update `img.src` with the new source whenever you change the field?

Comment: yea i need to listen when the input value changes cause the user can retake the photo and i am using this input value (base64) to store in the database as well

Comment: the problem is how to listen for a value changed by jquery?

Comment: Ah nice, other examples were with onload

Comment: @DominicTobias `onload` is required when loading an external resource, and there is no real harm in using it to be safe, but yes, when working with data URLs, there is no need for `onload`.

Comment: can I add text on it like  ctx.fillText("abcd",canvas.width/2,canvas.height*0.1);   it is not giving me text on image. as my image is base64Image